# Group data based on multiple column in spark using scala's API

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an `RDD`, want to group data based on multiple column. for large dataset spark cannot work using `combineByKey`, `groupByKey`, `reduceByKey` and `aggregateByKey`, these gives heap space error. Can you give another method for resolving it using Scala's API?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use `treeReduce()` for doing incremental reduce in Spark. However, you hypothesis that spark can not work on large dataset is not true, and I suspect you just don't have enough partitions in your data, so maybe a `repartition()` is what you need.